# Chrome/Chromium gives 404 for page that exists

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I'm having a weird problem with Chromium 26.0.1372.0 (174726).

I'm working on a webapp that fetches HTML pages via XHR. For some reason it loads `http://1.1.1.1/foo.html` perfectly but `http://1.1.1.1/foo_b.html` gives 404. Same script works in Safari/Firefox/Opera and if I access foo_b.html directly, Chromium finds it just fine. So this seems to be some sort of cache issue.

I already tried restarting the browser and emptied the cache but no help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe completly wrong but: the underscore can't be the problem? (it shouldn't but you never know, if it goes from UTF-8 to ascii). You can try with foo%5fb.html to verify...

Comment: I doubt it because both file names have multiple underscores in them unless Chromium has a magical underscore limit because b version has one _ more :)

Comment: It is from Google so I doubt every bit ;-)

Comment: Actually rene, you were right. I ran into this again and thought just for the fun of it I'm going to try your suggestion... Took out one underscore and it started to work - what the hell. It seems that 3 is too much but 2 is ok. This is really weird. Chromium ftw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like rene suggested in the comments for the question, it was too many underscores. It seems 2 underscores in the filename works but not 3.

Comment: Did I get it right? XHR has some magical internal limit on the number of underscores? Could show an example?

Comment: I don't know if this still true but when the question was asked/answered that was true at least with Chromium. We couldn't get any URL with more than 2 underscores to work. It just gave 404 to each. Meaning foo_bar_foo.html would work but not foo_bar_foo_bar.html would not.